# Parse.com - Remember the date of the first launch, being able to know that

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I'm deploying a little game for iOS platform. I'm using parse.com for in-app purchases.

I want to extend usage of parse a little bit. My game doesn't need login so everything further must be created without a login.

I want to remember the date when user launched the app for the very first time and than be able to give them badges as time passes. Badges will be stored as pics on parse.

The reason I want to use parse for that is security. I dont want users to change their current dates settings on their phones and trick the app. I bet I should use Cloud Code for that, but have no idea where to start.

I thought about using UUID for unique identifier, but read that it might change with iOS updates.

**Edit:** My current guesses are:

1. Somehow find a way to generate unique username and password, and log users behind the scenes.
2. Store empty object at parse associated with user so that it would fill createdAt and updateAt properties with valid dates and not the one user can set in the Settings.
3. Write a simple function on Cloud Code which gets that object for given user and counts time since that object was generated. Based on what this function returns I should do different things in my front end app. (Remove countdown or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because your users don't log in, doesn't mean you can't log them in behind the scenes. You can use the Parse SDK and its `PFUser.currentUser`. If the current user is `nil`, create one by signing up a new user (this creates a new user in Parse's database and logs the user in on the device). Now that device can reference the current user's creation date for anything time-dependent.

Comment: Well, I thought about that, but I cant use anonymous user functionality since the data is wiped when the user logs out, so I have to find a way to generate unique login a password, but I cant use UUID for that since Apple warns us that it could change with iOS update.

Comment: I thought you said the user doesn't have login/logout functionality. If the user can log out, could you just generate a password and save it in `NSUserDefaults`? This would disappear if the user deletes the app, but if there is no user login for your game, this would be the expected behavior.

Comment: as I understand from Parse docs anonymous users logs out when app is closed. I dont want users to know there is some login process going on

Comment: Oh I see. Don't use an anonymous user - use a regular user. Just generate a password.

Comment: What about it? Log in the user with whatever username and password you want. Since you'll just be using the SDK's `PFUser.currentUser`, you don't ever have to use the username and password again. And if you do need them for some reason, then you can store them on the device (at whatever level of security you need, user defaults, keychain, etc.).

Comment: How do I generate unique logins? Why do you think I wont need them? As I see I'll need to log in every time app launches to check if it is the right time to give a user access to a new feature or not.

Comment: Parse's SDK caches user sessions, so you don't need to log in, even if you close the app. Check out the documentation here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-current-user

Comment: Thats cool, but still, how do I give a unique login for each user, i dont want them to enter it

Comment: I think maybe you can use anonymous users for your use case, as long as you use the cached `currentUser` from the SDK. Check out the docs on anonymous users here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users.

Comment: As I mention before I considered using anonymous users but they are logged out when app is closed so it doesnt fit my needs.

Comment: Well, apparently my question is too broad and I guess you answered the most main part, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use local storage, that way they'd have to redownload the app for it to work. Example:

```
//App Delegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

if let date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("FIRST_LOGIN") {
    //They have logged in before
} else {
    //They haven't logged in before
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("anything-here", forKey: "FIRST_LOGIN")
}
```

But if you want it to all be on Parse, you could set up a user login system or use Game Center and then you could save data under that.

Comment: this way they could trick my app by switching date back and forth in the settings, I want the date to be stored at the backend and also to be setted by backend since I cant send NSDate object because it still can be faked by settings.

Comment: @s1ddok this wouldn't use NSDates, it would just create a locally stored variable that could be anything -- this just checks if it exists. If it exists, you know that the app has been started already before, and if not, then you set it.